# KML file not overlaying on google map in wordpress site

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, kml

So, I'm putting together a plugin that displays a google map and some markers on it and the customer would like the map to also display time zones. I've got a valid [KML file](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B45QP71QXoR0TnVxTWtUb2piVUk) that shows the time zones when uploaded to google drive and viewed from there, but it won't display on the map on my site. The javascript I'm using to display the map is

```
var map;
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 1,
    //styles: style,
    draggable: false,
    zoomControl: false,
    scrollwheel: false,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(30, 0),
    MapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    disableDefaultUI: true
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);

var timeZones = new google.maps.KmlLayer( {
    //url: php_data.mapKML, //DOESN'T WORK
    //url: 'https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B45QP71QXoR0TnVxTWtUb2piVUk/edit?usp=sharing', //DOESN'T WORK
    //url: 'http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ggeoxml/cta.kml', //WORKS
    map: map
});
```

I've tried all three of the commented out urls and only the one hosted on the gmaps-samples subdomain works. The `php_data.mapKML` is what I would ideally use. `php_data['mapKML']` is passed from wordpress using `wp_localize_script` and contains a valid url to the KML file. But even the link to the file on google docs doesn't seem to work. But it's not a problem with the file cause it shows up fine when viewed straight from google drive.

I thought it might be an access problem cause the site is hosted locally while I work on the plugin, but then the kml file hosted by google works fine.

I'm stumped. Maybe someone else can shed some light on this.

Comment: What is [KmlStatus](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlLayerStatus) when it fails?

Answer (score 0):

When you say "the site is hosted locally while I work on the plugin", does this mean that the site is not externally available? If this is the case, it won't work, because the KML needs to be accessible to the Google Server, not the Browser.

Comment: But URL #2, the one hosted on google drive and publicly shared doesn't work either.

Comment: Hmmm... Not sure then. It is certainly the case that the KML needs to be externally available though, so that's worth bearing in mind. Could it be an HTTP vs HTTPS issue?